# Erro na enumeração e print

Tags: python

Nesta lista as combinações aparecem. Mas não consigo enumerá-las. e quando imprimi a última soma total de 520. Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

```
from itertools import combinations 
lis = [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 
39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46]      
for i in (10, len(lis)):
    for comb in combinations(lis, i):
        if sum(comb) >= 280 <= 520:
            for c in enumerate(comb):
                print(comb)
```

Comment: `for i in (10, len(lis))`, poderia revisar esta linha?

Comment: Qual é exatamente o propósito do programa? O que ele deveria fazer?

Comment: Na verdade é para um exemplo sobre a mega sena. Percorrer sobre todos 60 números. Este exemplo não coloquei os 60 números. Onde o total dos 10 selecionados fiquem em 280 e 520 e cada linha seja enumerada.

Comment: Então, basicamente, gerar todas as combinações dos 60 números, tomados 10 a 10, em que a soma esteja entre 280 e 520?

Comment: Indicando a quantidade de linha que contém toda lista gerada.

Comment: Não necessariamente 10 a 10. Cada linha sem ser repetida da lista gerada a soma de 280 em posições distintas até a soma de 520 com posições diferentes.

Comment: O que está dizendo não está fazendo sentido nenhum para mim :(
Isso é um exercício? Se for, seria melhor postar o enunciado completo.

Comment: De onde vem esses números mágicos `280` e `520` ??

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um dicionario para resolver o seu problema.

Para se calcular *todas as combinações* nas quais o somatório das dezenas fique entre `280` e `520`:

```
from itertools import combinations

lis = [25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46]

dic = {}

for i in range(10, len(lis)):
    n = 0;
    for comb in combinations(lis, i):
        s = sum(comb);
        if 280 <= s <= 520:
            if s not in dic:
                dic[s] = []
            dic[s].append(comb)

print(dic[300]) # Exibe todas as combinacoes que o somatorio seja 300
```

Saída:

```
[
 (25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 39),
 (25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 38),
 (25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 35, 37),
 (25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 37),
 (25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 35, 36),
 (25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36),
 (25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35)
]
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/YLBQkv)